# gtk+ 3.x key bindings - struggling

Tags: c, gtk

I've tried a few things and may be nearing a solution but here goes ...

on a (possibly realised) widget, has anyone got a good example of say an
`GtkEntry` widget receiving a <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>Down</kbd>  or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> key press which will raise
a "new" signal e.g. `SIG-NEW` on the widget. which I know how to catch with `g_signal_connect`.

Answer (score 1):

I appended a minimal working example.

The important point is to connect the `key-press-event` of an `GtkEntry`-instance to a suitable callback. In that callback you have to extract the `GdkEventKey` struct that is a member of the `GdkEvent` struct which is a parameter of the callback function.

`GdkEventKey` contains all information you need to check which key+modifier was pressed.

Since i tested the code with `gtk+-3.0` you may have to modify the `GdkEventMask` of the widget to receive `key-press-event`'s. For `gtk+-3.0` it seems that is already the default setting. If the callback isn't invoked you should enable it with `gdk_window_set_events ()` (of course you have to invoke it upon the gdk window of the widget).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

gboolean
key_press_event_cb (GtkWidget * widget, GdkEvent * event,
                    gpointer data)
{
    GdkEventKey key = event->key;

    /* check modifier key */
    /* on most keyboards GDK_MOD1_MASK is the Alt key */
    if (key.state == GDK_MOD1_MASK) {

        /* check for key that was pressed */
        switch (key.keyval) {
            case GDK_KEY_d:
                g_print
                    ("`Alt-d` deletes the content in the entry box\n");
                gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (widget), "");
                break;
        }

    }

    /* check for unmodified key presses */
    switch (key.keyval) {
        case GDK_KEY_x:
            g_print
                ("`x` deletes the content in the entry box\n");
            gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (widget), "");
            return TRUE;
            break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *entry;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    entry = gtk_entry_new ();

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), entry);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
                      G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (entry, "key-press-event",
                      G_CALLBACK (key_press_event_cb), NULL);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to mask `key.state` with [gtk-accelerator-get-default-mod-mask()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accelerator-get-default-mod-mask) so you don't get confused by the state of caps lock and num lock etc.